# Google: Bigquery does not have option to import from specific google-drive-sheet1

Tags: google-bigquery

In one GoogleSheet, I have two tables, in sheet1 I have table EXP1_ASTROCYTOMA, in sheet2 I have table EXP1_GLIOBLASTOMA.

Is there a way to import that into bigquery dataset by choosing Sheet1 to one table and sheet 2 to another table?

It does not import sheet2!

Comment: few questions before I can answer: 1) are you bound to using native BQ UI; 2) do you mean load data from non first sheet or create external table based on spreadsheet's non-first sheet?

Comment: Experiment data in multiple sheets i.e GS:s1, GS:s2 of a single GoogleSeet. What i need is a way to import GS:s1 into Table1,  GS:s2 into Table2. Importing makes queries faster than having it as external table.   So multiple problems (1) only first sheet importing is supported (2) Moving sheets around corrupts table as tables point to EXTERNAL DATA, there is no option to "import into BQ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery we can import the data from the specific sheets. Refer the **Sheet range** field in the import screen. I tried importing the specific sheet by mentioning its name and its working.

[image]

Comment: you've got lucky to be in proper bin of what most likely looks to me as A/B testing. This feature is not yet available for all (at least at a time of writing this comment) !

Comment: Mikhail is right, this feature isn't available for everybody. I also don't see filed for sheet range.

Comment: oh, I have 2 GCP accounts, both are having this option.

Answer (score 0):

Update after discussion in comments:

BigQuery exports data only from 1st sheet(tab) of your spreadsheet file.

1.If your objective is to do export from tab 1, run query, save output and do same for tab 2, do this: 
Just click on 2nd sheet(tab) and drag it on 1st position, then create table on BQ side with same link to sheets as before.

2. If you need to have BQ tables from each tab on regular base:
   Create new spreadsheet and do [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) of your 2nd tab there. Than use 2 different sheets as datasources of 2 BQ tables.

Comment: Oh I tried that already, what it does is changes the fist table to point to that new-first-sheet. Those seem to be pointers to external data rather than copying data into bigquery space.

Comment: Sorry, not sure that I get your case. You already did it but it still doesn't  import sheet2 to BQ_table2?

Comment: A BQ_table2 will be created, that will point to the sheet2 that was moved to the left. However BQ_table1 which was already pointing to that Sheet1 will endup pointing ot sheet2. So both BQ_table1 and BQ_table2 will be pointing to Sheet2 at the end of the operation.

Comment: Oh, I see, originally I decided that you just want to run 1 time query for each sheet, but now I get you problem. Unfortunately there no way to define sheet(tab) in BQ ui right now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905674 . But you can create new spreadsheet doc and do =IMPORTRANGE for your 2nd tab of original spreadsheet. And finally use 2 different sources for 2 different BQ tables.